# Background of absolutely positioned div is larger than expected (seemingly larger than its size indicates)

Tags: javascript, css

Below is a simplified example of code in a project I'm working on. Can you please help me understand and resolve, why the background of the g div, appears higher up and further left, when it's top is 10px, and it's left is 10px, just like p-1, the image inside it?

So, once again, why does the background extend higher than the 640x480 image, and why does it extend further to the left.  Please note the console.log statements to help debug -- there should be nothing "fancy here", meaning why doesn't everything just start/appear at left, top: 10px, 10px

```js
var toggle = false;
function id(name) { return document.getElementById(name); }
function run() {
 
id('p-1').style.left = "10px"
id('p-1').style.top = "10px"
id('p-2').style.left = "660px"
id('p-2').style.top = "500px"

var w1 = id("p-1").clientWidth; 
var h1 = id("p-1").clientHeight; 
var l1 = id("p-1").style.left.replace("px", "");
var t1 = id("p-1").style.top.replace("px", "");
  
var w2 = id("p-2").clientWidth;
var h2 = id("p-2").clientHeight; 
var l2 = id("p-2").style.left.replace("px", "");
var t2 = id("p-2").style.top.replace("px", "");

  // "math" for the g size and position
  var wOverlay = l2 - w1;
  var hOverlay = t2 - h1;
 
  var wg = w1 + w2 + wOverlay;
  var hg = h1 + h2 + hOverlay;
  
  var lg = ( l1 < l2 ) ? l1 : l2;
  var tg = ( t1 < t2 ) ? t1 : t2;
  console.log("p-1: (l,t)=(" +l1+ "," +t1+ "), (w, h) = (" +w1+ "," +h1+ ").");
  console.log("p-2: (l,t)=(" +l2+ "," +t2+ "), (w, h) = (" +w2+ "," +h2+ ").");
  console.log("g: (l,t)=(" +lg+ "," +tg+ "), (w, h) = (" +wg+ "," +hg+ ").");
  
 id('g').style.left = lg + "px";
 id('g').style.top = tg + "px";
  
 id('g').style.width =  wg + "px";
 id('g').style.height = hg + "px"; 
 console.log("div (l,t)=(" +id('g').style.left+ "," +id('g').style.top+ "), (width, height) = (" +id('g').style.width+ "," +id('g').style.height+ ").");

}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.item {
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Div</title>

</head>
<body onload="run();">
<div class="item" id="g" style="background-color:gold;">
  <img id="p-1" class="item" src="https://dummyimage.com/640x4:3/"> 
  <img id="p-2" class="item" src="https://dummyimage.com/300/09f.png/fff">  
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `#p-1` and `#p-2` are absolutely positioned children of absolutely positioned `#g` - that means they are positioned relative to their parent (ie `#g`), not entire viewport. You've set `left: 10px; top: 10px;` for `#p-1` - therefore, it offsets itself `10px` from top and `10px` from left of `#g`. If you want `#p-1` to be positioned relative to _viewport_ - you may want to set `position: fixed;` for it. Another solution is to set `top: 0; left: 0;` for `#p-1`.